# In what sense, Taylor series at $x=0$ is better than Taylor series at $x=a$, and vice-versa?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series

In the book `Calculus Early Transcendentals (6th Edition)' by James Stewart, on p. 739, the author writes:

> We have two series representations for $e^x$ as follows:
> $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n! , \forall x\in \mathbb R$$
> $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (e^2 (x-2)^n)/n! , \forall x\in \mathbb R.$$
> The first is better if we are interested in values of $x$ near $0$ and the second is better if $x$ is near 2.

My question is: ``Better in what sense?''. Since both the series are equal to $e^x$, so they will result the same value $e^{0.1}$ if we put $x=0.1$ (near $0$) in them, and also they will result the same value $e^{2.1}$ if we put $x=2.1$ (near $2$) in them. So what is meant by saying `better' by James Stewart?

Comment: The infinite series are both equal to $e^x$, sure. But assume we want to approximate the value of $e^x$ by a rational number. Question is, for which $N$ will the sum of the first $N$ terms be "sufficiently close" to $e^x$? If $x$ is close to $0$ then we will need a smaller $N$ (i.e we will have to sum less terms) if we use the Taylor series around $0$. If $x$ is close to $2$ then we will need a smaller $N$ in the series around $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Now, suppose we do approximation up to $3$ terms and evaluate it at $x=0.1$.

We can see that the blue and red curve and very close to each other at $x=0.1$ while the green line, the approximation resulting from $x=2$ is very far from it.
[image]

They will coincide when we use infinitely many terms but the usual application numerically is when we use finitely many terms.

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in the other answers, the comment concerns the use of a fixed number of terms in both series. In the graphic below is plotted the error when using $a=0$ (blue) and $a=2$ (Orange), for $x \in [0,2]$.

[image]